# How can I display this multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I have created a multidimentional array called 'orders'. But I have no idea how I can display it to the visitor in a readable way. How can I display it in a table or something?

How I would like to display it:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cake</td>
    <td>ingredient1</td>
    <td>ingredient2</td>
    <td>ingredient3</td>
    <td>ingredient</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Chocolate Cookie</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- And go on... -->
 </table>
```

This is the array:

```
array(5) {
 [0]=>
   array(2) {
      [0]=> string(4) "Cake"
      [1]=> array(5) {
          [0]=> string(11) "ingredient1"
          [1]=> string(11) "ingredient2"
          [2]=> string(11) "ingredient3"
          [3]=> string(11) "ingredient4"
          [4]=> string(11) "ingredient5"
          }
    }
 [1]=> array(2) {
     [0]=> string(16) "Chocolate Cookie"
     [1]=> string(1) "5"
     }
 [2]=> array(2) {
     [0]=> string(15) "Chocolate cakes"
     [1]=> string() "10"
     }
 [3]=>
   array(2) {
      [0]=> string(6) "Cookie"
      [1]=> array(3) {
          [0]=> string(11) "ingredient1"
          [1]=> string(11) "ingredient2"
          [2]=> string(11) "ingredient3"
          }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in php by following method

```
 $array=array();
  $array[0]=array(0 => 'cake',1 =>array(0 => 'ingredient1',1 => 'ingredient1',2 => 'ingredient1'));
  $array[1]=array(0 => 'pizza',1 =>array(0 => 'ingredient11',1 => 'ingredient12',2 => 'ingredient13'));

$html='<table>';
foreach($array as $arr){
$newarray=""; //Intialization
$html.='<tr>';
$html.='<td>'.$arr[0].'</td>';
$newarrays=$arr[1];
foreach($newarrays as $newarr){
$html.='<td>'.$newarr.'</td>';
}
$html.='</tr>';
}
$html.="</table>";
echo $html;
```

Please check and let me know if you want in the same way

Thanks

Comment: Works great, but I get the following error:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). On the line of foreach($newarrays as $newarr). I get the error for all the 'arrays' that have no ingredients, but just some name like chocolate cookie

Comment: Can you please share the screen shot or share the array i will have a look over it. i will help to fix !!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following structure will be helpful:

Since you have another array under Cake and need to show a list inside a tr so I recommend to nested table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Cake
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        indegredent1
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        indegredent2
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        indegredent3
                    </td>
                </tr>
                    <td>
                        indegredent4
                    </td>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        indegredent5
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Chocolate cake
        </td>
        <td>
            5
        </td>
    </tr>
    and so on...
</table>
```